# Conjecture about a continued fraction

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, proof-writing, conjectures, continued-fractions

> > **Conjecture:**
>
> $$\large 2^{n-1}+\frac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{2^{n}-1+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{2^{n}-1+\cfrac{1}{2+\ddots}}}}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{3a_n}}{2}\tag*{[1]}$$ such that $a_n=4a_{n-1}+1$ and $a_0=0$.$\quad(n\geqslant 1)$

---

Ex. If $n=1$, then $a_n=4a_0+1=4\times 0 + 1 = 1$. $$\therefore 1+\frac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{1+\cfrac{1}{2+\ddots}}}}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}\tag*{[2]}$$ This can be proven using the formula $x=a+\dfrac{1}{b+\dfrac{1}{x}}=a+\dfrac{1}{b+\dfrac{1}{a+\dfrac{1}{b+\dfrac{1}{a+\ddots}}}}$

Solving for $x$ results in a quadratic equation for which $x=\dfrac12\left\{a+\sqrt{a\left(a+\dfrac4b\right)}\right\}$.

Substituting $a=1$ and $b=2$ yields $[2]$ as required.

---

Problem is, I am unsure on how to (dis)prove this conjecture given the recursive sequence involved. How do I appropriately go about this? Any suggestions or counter-examples?

Thanks :)

Comment: Apparently, you are sure about the value of the continued fraction. Maybe, you formulate the conjecture with those values. Then, we might get a statement easier to be proven.

Comment: @Peter what do you mean?

Comment: The formula for $x$ is the value of the continued fraction, right ?

Comment: @Peter not entirely, due to the first summand, but pretty much. I just don't know how to apply it with the recursive.

Comment: $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n 2^i$ can be written in a compact way a $2^{n+1}-1$

Comment: @JeanMarie oh my I didn't know that, lol. I edited the question accordingly. Thanks! :)

Comment: $a_n={4^n-1\over 3}$ meaning $1+\sqrt {3a_n}\approx 2^n+1$

Comment: See number $s$ in "conjecture 1" of [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2016-144-05/S0002-9939-2015-12848-1/S0002-9939-2015-12848-1.pdf) which has similarities with yours.

Comment: Your conjecture is false even for $n=1$. Note that $2^{n+1}-1=3$, not $1$ for $n=1$.

Comment: @mathlove typo fixed. Apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Claim:**

For all $n\ge1$, we have $[2^{n-1},2,2^n-1,2,2^n-1,\cdots]=(1+\sqrt{3a_n})/2$ with $a_n=4a_{n-1}+1$ and $a_0=0$.

**Proof:**

As $a_n=4a_{n-1}+1=4^2a_{n-2}+4^1+4^0=\cdots=4^ka_{n-k}+\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}4^i$, choosing $k=n$ gives $$a_n=4^na_0+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}4^i=\frac{4^n-1}3\implies\frac{1+\sqrt{3a_n}}2=\frac{1+\sqrt{4^n-1}}2.$$ We know that the continued fraction converges by the Seidel-Stern theorem, as the sum of the convergents diverges. Thus, writing the continued fraction as $y=2^{n-1}+x=2^{n-1}+[0,2,2^n-1+x]$, $$2+\frac1{2^n-1+x}=\frac1x\implies2x(2^n-1+x)+x=2^n-1+x$$ giving the quadratic $$2x^2+2(2^n-1)x-(2^n-1)=0\implies x=-\frac{2^n-1}2\pm\frac{\sqrt{4^n-1}}2.$$ Evidently, the positive root must be chosen so that $y=(1+\sqrt{4^n-1})/2$ as required.

Comment: Congratulations! I knew about the first part, but have never heard of the Seidel-Stern theorem until now. Well done, and thanks! :) $\color{green}{\checkmark}$